# Overide JWT so that a user can register via a mobile device

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm using [JWT](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) with Django-rest-framework.  How can I write an `APIView` that won't need a JSON web token so that my users can  sign up?  Is there a decorator I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.  To override token authentication to protected `APIViews` set `permission_classes = (AllowAny,)`

```
class SomeView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```